# Flexbox Layout—Header, Auto Content, Sticky Footer—Not Styling Consistent in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, flexbox, sticky-footer

I'm trying to get a sticky footer layout to work cross-browser. Philip Walton seems to have done it perfectly as demonstrated [here—https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/).

I'm using flexbox and prefixes correctly as far as I know. But I know I make mistakes! Any help is very appreciated! I haven't posted code because I think this is something that is just easiest when debugged in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to clean up your code first, as current IE11, FF and CH as well use -webkit prefixes or even plain CSS3. Dunno vendor stuff ordering of SCSS.

But in general, making a sticky header/footer is very simple with flexbox:

- container: a column of 3 rows, => **display: flex; justify-content: space-between**
- row one: (header) fixed height => no specific flexbox code
- row two: (content) flexed height => **flex: 1**
- row three: (footer) fixed height =>  no specific flexbox code

Modify min/max height/widths of the elements to meet your needs

'**space-between**' on three rows (or columns), flexing the middle one yields the desired result, couldn't be easier.

Comment: I do appreciate your intention to help but your comment isn't helpful. `space-between` is not what's needed here. Also, my SCSS is irrelevant. I just use it to output CSS which is all we're looking at. And closing your comment with "couldn't be easier" is belittling. Maybe you didn't intend it to be that way but I would suggest choosing your words more carefully. I'm quite advanced with CSS so what's you point by saying that? Again, I honestly do appreciate that you would take the time to look at my problem and offer help. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Sorry, no pun intended at all. It'll probably sounds better in Dutch (my native tongue). Mean't as 'here you go' or something like that. BTW: I was working ome the same problem the week before and eventually needed only 2 lines of CSS.